# Return list of rows that match a list of values using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have query that receives a list of items that all contain a different ID that I need to search for in a different table. for example here's my first table class:

```
public class Presave
    {
        public int PresaveID { get; set; }
        public int ArtistID { get; set; }
        public string AlbumName { get; set; }
        public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<UserPresave> UserPresaves { get; set; }
    }
```

and then my other class that I need to search through:

```
public class UserPresave
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public int PresaveID { get; set; }
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    public virtual Presave Presave { get; set; }
}
```

There is a one (presave) to many (userpresave) relationship between these two.

I would like to search for all the `UserPresave` that contain the same `PresaveID` as the `Presave` class I pass. But note that this `PresaveID` is not the same for each `Presave` element in the list. I thought this query would work:

```
public static List<UserPresave> GetAllUserPresavesByPresaveIDs(List<Presave> ids)
{
    using (var Context = GetContext())
    {
        return Context.UserPresaves.Where(x => x.PresaveID == ids.Contains(x.PresaveID)).ToList();
    }
}
```

But I get an error under `x.Presave` stating that I cannot convert from `int` to `presave`. Where did I go wrong? Thanks!

I got this query concept from this SO question! https://stackoverflow.com/a/36164453/6480913

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your function as shown:

```
 public static List<UserPresave> GetAllUserPresavesByPresaveIDs(List<Presave> ids)
 {
     var hs = new HashSet<int>(ids.Select(x=>x.PresaveID));
     using (var Context = GetContext())
     {
         return Context.UserPresaves.Where(x => hs.Contains(x.PresaveID)).ToList();
     }
 }
```

Your problem was that you were using types inconsistently. Using a HashSet here will increase the performance drastically for larger data sets.

Comment: that worked! Also thanks for that extra nugget of information, I need to read up more about lambda expressions and hashsets. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...You can retrieve data from Presaves table and then will bring associated data from UserPresaves table

```
public static List<UserPresave> GetAllUserPresavesByPresaveIDs(List<Presave> ids)
        {
            using (var Context = GetContext())
            {
                return Context.Presaves.Where(p => p.UserPresaves.Any(a => ids.Contains(a.Presave))).ToList();
            }
        }
```